# How to substitute Currency Strings for Symbols in Android App?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, currency

Coming from Python I am trying to create an Android App. I now have something working, which is supposed to display amounts in several currencies. In my DB I have the currencies stored as three-letter Strings ("EUR", "GBP", "USD", etc.). Since I want to display the symbols for the currencies (€, £, $) I was thinking of how to do this.

I could of course create an if-elseif-elseif-etc., but that doesn't seem the best solution. I need to be able to reuse the code in different parts of the app and getting the code into a separate file seems more logical, maybe in some kind of Dictionary-like structure.

As far as I understand though I *always* need to create a class in Java. Does that also mean that I *always* need to create an instance/object of the class before I can use the functions within the class?

So to come to my question; does anybody know how I could solve this substitute-currency-strings-for-symbols problem? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 5):

One limited solution is to use `java.util.Currency`. You can do something like the following

```
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance("EUR");
System.out.println(currency + " " + currency.getSymbol(Locale.ITALY));
```

which prints

```
EUR €
```

It's **limited** because you need to know a `Locale` that would map `EUR` correctly to the symbol. If instead we had

```
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance("EUR");
System.out.println(currency + " " + currency.getSymbol(Locale.CANADA));
```

it would print

```
EUR EUR
```

Comment: No, that's not limited, thats perfect! I have the currency string, so that will get me the symbol! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @kramer65 No, sadly, the currency String is not enough. You need a corresponding `Locale`.

Comment: getSymbol also works without supplying it with a locale. Check http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Currency.html . Thanks for the solution!

Comment: @kramer65 Slow down, lol. You'll notice it says it's equivalent to `getSymbol(Locale.getDefault())`. Your default locale might not be able to convert the string code to a symbol.

Comment: Hmmm, you're right. Most of the times this will work fine, but this indeed means that if a person in Canada wants to use EUR, it will fail. Strange actually, because EUR cannot refer to anything else than to €, just like USD cannot refer to anything else than $.. Any other solutions? Would you also have a suggestion in which I can maybe create a dictionary-like object to map strings to symbols or something?

Comment: @kramer65 You can start by building your own by looking at the ISO currency references. You might find some ready made MySQL tables on the net.